# Optional Parameters in Azure Api Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am creating Operations in Azure Api Managerment and wants to create Optional Parameters. anybody knows how this can be accomplished ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Required" check box for each parameter.

Comment: Worth adding not to look for the "required" box in the "URL template parameters" sections (these are all required), but below that there is a "Query parameters" section. Add the query parameters there. Also the URL template shall not contain the optional query parameters, so instead of `/api/customers?q={queryString}` the URL template should only be `/api/customers`, and add `q` to the "Query parameters" section. It will then be treated as an optional parameter.

Comment: How can you read optional parameters when building your body in a liquid template? I'm trying to use context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("param","") but I'm not getting any results.

Comment: @TimD'haeyer Did you ever get an answer to that question?